# Can't receive attribute of python objects transferred as json to js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

Transferring django objects queryset to js via json serialisation.

```
 result = Event.objects.filter(title__istartswith=key)
 events = serializers.serialize('json', result)

 data = {
    'events': events,

}
 return Response(data)
```

In js function it's successfully parsed,

```
 var sed = JSON.parse(data['events'])
         alert(JSON.stringify(sed))
```

The result look like this:

```
[{"model":"app.event","pk":66,"fields":{"city":"Запорожье","title":"Приглашение на казнь","date":" 04 апреля 2017 г","hashtag":"Театры","place":"Запорожский областной академический украинский музыкально-драматический театр им В.Г.Магара","image_link":"https://image.karabas.com/w/350/h/496/f/files/import/1100376762_ImageBig636196519366969017.jpg","description":"\nСпектакль Приглашение на казнь в Запорожье состоится 04 апреля 2017 г, 19:00. "}},{"model":"app.event","pk":94,"fields":{"city":"Киев","title":"Птицы или просто Моль","date":" 05 апреля 2017 г","hashtag":"Театры","place":"Театр «Дивний замок»","image_link":"https://image.karabas.com/w/350/h/496/f/files/import/1037587642_ImageBig636156960481061608.jpg","description":"\nСпектакль Птицы или просто Моль в Киеве состоится 05 апреля 2017 г, 19:00."}]
```

But the following code doesn't work, I thought it might work this way:

```
for (var e in sed) {

                          alert(e.title)

                      }
```

But it's just undefined. Also tried

```
 alert(e['title'])
```

This might be correct, but even alert doesn't work if I try like this:

```
 for (var e in data) {

                          alert(e.fields.title);

                      }
```

Didn't help as well. How to receive data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your json structure, i think it should be `e.fields.title`

Comment: {"events":"[{\"model\": \"app.event\", \"pk\": 6, \"fields\": {\"place\": \"\\u0414\\u043e\\u043c \\u0410\\u0440\    .......yeah, I also tried  e.fields.title    
but it didn't work